# prove that for any natural number $n$, and any real number $0<a<1, a^n \le a$

Tags: induction

my question is as the title says. I've tried proving by induction but got stuck:
for $n=1$, $$a^1\le a$$
now assumimg that $$a^n \le a$$ for every $$ a \in \mathbb{R}, 0<a<1, n \in \mathbb{N}$$
now for the induction step: prove that
$$ a^{n+1} \le a $$
$$a^n * a \le a$$
since
$$ 0<a<1$$
and more specifically
$$a \neq 0$$
we can divide by a, such that
$$ a^n \le 1 $$
using the assumption, we know that
$$a^n \le a <1 $$
and therefore
$$a^n < 1$$
but I couldn't understand how to prove that
$$ a^n \le 1 $$

Sorry for any possible mistakes, I've never posted before and English is not my mother language. Thanks a lot.

Comment: $> \implies \ge$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove $\forall n \in\Bbb N$, $0 &lt; a &lt; 1$ $\implies$ $a^n \leq 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876600/prove-forall-n-in-bbb-n-0-a-1-implies-an-leq-1). With this other question, $n \ge 0$, so multiplying both sides by $a$ gives $a^n \leq 1 \iff a^{n+1} \leq a$.